# Query Optimization (Function Vs SubQuery)

Tags: mysql, performance, query-optimization

In MYSQL Is it better to use function(included that subquery) in a store procedure instead of direct writing subquery, does it make any difference or is it just for code reuse?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to that is quite simple: Give it a try and measure the results; preferably on a test-set that is realistic. (You might not see much difference when there are only 2 records in your table, but the effect on 2 million records could be gigantic)

You can test it in this way:

```
$starttime = microtime(true);
// your codes
$endtime = microtime(true);
echo $duration = $endtime - $starttime;
```

IMHO, a subquery will most likely be (a lot) faster than the same functionality stored in a function. But I'm MSSQL-biased and can't quite tell if MySQL would be different; but I very much doubt it.

Answer (score 0):

using function (included that subquery) has better performance, when you define a function, the function will not run while calling the function. I mean that you may have multiple sub-query, then using function makes to be called those that you need.

And on the other hand, using the function will be sorting your codes and that is valuable in developing.

Comment: Although I agree about the fact that using functions (probably) will keep your code cleaner and easier to read, I very much doubt it will be faster, especially if the function needs to go to the database itself.

Comment: using function is not returning positive result in terms of performance. so i think after all analysis i did, its better to use subquery directly when its about millions of records

Answer (score 0):

I have analyzed, in store procedure i got the difference by 5sec to 1sec when i added sub-query directly instead of a function.
I am currently working in mysql

Comment: thanks for the feedback! (although you could just have put it as a comment on your question for everyone to see =)